# Winner of a tournament in O(N) and rank of the players in O(NLogN)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

In a tennis tournament of N players every player plays with every other player. 
The following condition always hold- 
If player P1 has won the match with P2 and player P2 has won from P3, then Player P1 has also defeated P3. 
Find winner of tournament in O(N) time and O(1) space. Find rank of players in O(NlogN) time.
**My Solution :**
The input is a boolean matrix where element matrix[i][j] indicates whether player i wins player j.

```
bool win[][]= {
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}
};
```

So the winner could be found like,

```
int winner = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < PLAYER_COUNT; ++i) {
    if (win[i][winner])
        winner = i;
}
return winner;
```

For getting the rank of the players, I guess Topological sorting will be the good one. If Player 1 wins Player 2, then an edge is added lke this  P1-> P2. If the Player 1 is winner here, then it would have edges to all the other players. Then topological sorting with winner as the source vertex, will give the rank of the player. 
Is my solution correct ? Is there any other efficient solution ? Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code. If there is a _specific_ error feel free to ask. This is no "do my homework", code-review or tutorial site.

Comment: the condition you mentioned that always holds is too strong. this condition shall make a player wins everybody. that should be the criteria of your search function. according to my eyeball, in this case, it's player number 2.

Comment: Also: C and C++ are **different** languages.

Comment: Isn't the winner always the one with only one zero in his line? (in this case #2)

Comment: @KennyOstrom the input doesn't lack symmetry: the diagonal matrix[n][n] is always 0 and all matrix[n][m]== !matrix[m][n].

Comment: I might be wrong, but there seems to be a logical problem in your winning conditions: If every player plays agains all other players, why does *P1 winning against P2 and P2 winning against P3* imply *P1 winning against P3*? Isn't the last result independent of the first two? Please make that a bit more clear in your question.

Comment: I think it's an ideal world where each player has a quantifiable skill level, and the better player always wins, thus eliminating most of the complications of real data.

Comment: even though the question itself is trivial. but given that condition, i think it would be a good math work to do to prove that actually finding the winner is O(n). i have a feeling it's indeed the upper bound.

Comment: @Jefffrey you don't have to walk through the whole matrix. you start with random player, then find somebody who wins that guy, and iterate, until you can't find anybody wins him. i think it smells O(n) indeed.

Comment: That's what he did.  The answer given in the original question looks good, if I am interpreting the original problem correctly.  (Thanks for the edit to line up the matrix, btw).

Comment: @andreas : there is no necessary for all the players to play against all the players. if P1 winning against P2 and P2 winning against P3, then the rows corresponding to P1, P2 and P3 are updated.

Comment: @vignesh but that is what your post says: *In a tennis tournament of N players every player plays with every other player.* That's why I was asking for clarification.

Answer (score 6):

The condition

> If player P1 has won the match with P2 and player P2 has won from P3

Is defining a total ordering, i.e. if we define `P1 < P2` for "`P2` defeated `P1`", we have a transitive ordering relation `<`, which can be used exactly as the regular `less-than` relation in either sorting or finding the maximum. So for the implementation we can define the predicate `bool lessThan(int p1, int p2)` which will simply look up `p1` and `p2` relation in the matrix in `O(1)`. And then use the predicate for "maximum" search, which is linear (`O(N)`), or for sorting (ranking), which is `O(N log N)`.

Comment: How do we deploy the less-than predicate to sort n log n?

Comment: @abksrv Choose any decent sorting algorithm running in `O(n log n)` (merge sort, heap sort)  and use this predicate for comparison in it instead of `<` .

Comment: Quickselect and Quicksort would be good choices in practice, but require modification to guarantee O(n) and O(n log n) in worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach for finding a winner seems correct. Indeed, assume the real winner number is `W`. When in your loop you have `i==W`, you will always have `win[i][winner]==1`, because player `W` has won everybody else. Therefore you will set `winner=W`, and will never more change it, because nobody has won over `W`.

Your code is also `O(N)`, so I think it solves the first problem.

For the second problem, yes, topological sort would do, but a simple implementation will be `O(N^2)`. However, note that your `win` table actually provides [strict total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_total_order). Therefore you can just apply any standard sorting algorithm, and compare two players simply checking whether one has won over another. That is, just use

```
bool less(int playerA, int playerB) {
    return win[playerA][playerB];
}
```

in `std::sort`.

This concept of strict total order also provides an alternative proof for you algorithm for finding a winned.

Here is the full code for your example: http://ideone.com/99DIQk

Comment: But in this case we have to compare each player with every other right ? So, that makes O(N2) right ?

Comment: @vignesh, many sorting algorithms use only `O(N log N)` comparisons.

Comment: No, I am asking about this function bool less(int playerA, int playerB)

Comment: @vignesh, this function just compares two given players and does this in `O(1)`. So each call to `less` is `O(1)`, while the total number of such calls is `O(N log N)`.

Comment: Could you please explain it with a simple exapmle of 4 players ?

Comment: @vignesh, I've added an ideone link with a working example. Note that the matrix `win` itself I consider given, and thus do not count the time to obtain it.